# How apply modifiers for list of address in array

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs

I want the owner of the smart contract to give/add authorization to the user of the modifier . and the only the users in the array will have access to the certain functions.

How to make modifier to check the list of the address.?

```
contract Owned {
    address owner;
    address[] listuser;
    function Owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function whitelistAddress (address user) onlyOwner {
        //add users address to the listuser array
    }   

    modifier onlyusers() {
        //How can i assign access to users address in the array listuser
        require();
        _;
    }

    function accessbyonlyusers () onlyusers {
    }
}
```

I want the function accessonlyusers to be accessed my list of address in the listusers

Answer (score 2):

As @ivicaa said, this is better implemented as a mapping. Here's the full implementation for that:

```
contract Owned {
    address owner;
    mapping(address=>bool) allowedUsers;
    function Owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function whitelistAddress (address user) onlyOwner {
        allowedUsers[user]=true;
    }   

    modifier onlyusers() {
        //How can i assign access to users address in the array listuser
        require(allowedUsers[msg.sender]);
        _;
    }

    function accessbyonlyusers () onlyusers {
        //Only runs if the user is whitelisted
    }
}
```

However, if you absolutely can't do this because users is an array anyway, here is how this could be implemented as an array (this will be more expensive since you're iterating over a boundless array, which is generally bad practice in the EVM)

```
contract Owned {
    address owner;
    address[] listuser;
    function Owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function whitelistAddress (address user) onlyOwner {
        listuser.push(user);
    }   

    modifier onlyusers() {
        //How can i assign access to users address in the array listuser

        for(uint index = 0; index < listuser; index++){
            if(userlist[index]==msg.sender){
                _;
                return;
            }
        }
        revert(); 
    }

    function accessbyonlyusers () onlyusers {
        //Only runs if the user is whitelisted
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, In this code Owner can add access to different address . can he also revoke/blacklist the access  to user. can this code be helpful for the same ?

function blacklistAddress (address user) onlyOwner {
        allowedUsers[user]=false;
    }

Answer (score 1):

It's more handy and it's better for the performance to have a mapping.

```
...
mapping (address => bool) users;
...
require(users[msg.sender]);
...
```